# OpenCart get Product Viewes

Tags: php, opencart

First i should say i couldn't login into OC Support forum somehow, hope get solution here.

Trying to show **Product Viewes** in **Product Page**, I googled and found out how can to get another data from OC database and show it up on Product Page, so here is:

**controller - product.php:**

```
$data['viewed'] = $product_info['viewed'];
```

**template - product.php;**

```
<?php echo $viewed; ?>
```

**but get error:**

> Undefined variable: viewed in
>
> /homepages/5/xxxxxx/htdocs/xxxxx/catalog/view/theme/xxxxx/template/product/product.tpl

According to this [Post](https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=121&t=103442) i did right way, but i don't know why got get this error? any idea?

here is part of template code:

```
<h1><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>
<?php echo $viewed; ?>
<ul class="list-unstyled product-info">
<li><b><?php echo $text_stock; ?></b> <span class="Stock"><?php echo $stock; ?></span></li>
<li><b><?php echo $text_model; ?></b> <span class="Model"><?php echo $model; ?></span></li>
<?php if ($manufacturer) { ?>
<li><b><?php echo $text_manufacturer; ?></b> <a href="<?php echo $manufacturers; ?>"><?php echo $manufacturer; ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
<li><b><?php echo $text_category; ?></b> <span>
<?php if( $categories ): ?>
<?php foreach( $categories as $category ): ?>
<a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a><span class="Comma"> ، </span>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</span></li>
<?php if ($reward) { ?>
<li><b><?php echo $text_reward; ?></b> <span class="reward-points"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo $reward; ?></span></li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: That would be the right way to do it normally. I do not get why your echoing $thumb in your template but your asking about an error that your controller is not seeing a "viewed" key. Have you passed $data to the template? Did you maybe declare $data['viewed'] after outputting the template? Have you tried using echo $viewed;?

Comment: sorry, anwer edited, i removed all that codes and write example here and it was my mistake, yes i tried to echo viewed, not thumb. @Yolo

Comment: well seems all correct. can you post the part where you output your template?

Comment: Which version of opencart are you using?

Comment: @LucasKrupinski 2.0.3.1

Comment: I'm only looking at 2.3, so things are probably different. But where in your controller did you add this new line? I assume you did so within the if($product_info) block? Because doing so in 2.3 let me echo the number of views on my product page. Sorry I can't be of more help... I'll look and see if I can find 2.0.3.1 easily :)

Comment: @LucasKrupinski i added this line after `$data['model'] = $product_info['model'];` as told in OC topic that i mentioned in answer. i also tried in `$data['products'][] = array(` but no success. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you are editing the theme template and not the default template?

Comment: @Yolo yeah sure, i get error in my template not default.

Comment: yes exactly why i asked. maybe you were editing the default template without noticing while loading the unedited theme template.. i am out of ideas tbh. Maybe you can show us your controller php script as last resort :)

Comment: I just reinstalled OC 2.0.3.1 and added `$data['viewed'] = $product_info['viewed'];` to line 164 of `/catalog/controller/product/product.php`and added `<php echo $viewed; ?>` to the product.tpl file, and it worked fine... Unfortunately, as now I'm at a loss since I can't recreate it.

Comment: @LucasKrupinski i did same, but still not working. can you tell me what codes are before or after line 164?

Comment: It goes `if($product_info) {`(new line) `$url = '';` (new line) `$data['viewed'] = $product_info['viewed'];`

Comment: @Yolo here is controller file http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/601cd520b13cd49b939424cc7613b9bedabf74e0

Comment: @LucasKrupinski weird.. i insert code same as you, but still same error. :/

Comment: @LucasKrupinski what about tpl file? which line you inserted?

Comment: The controller is not the problem @pedram. "viewed" is declared fine and  has to show up if you really added the line in your template file defined in config_template.

Comment: I added to product.tpl, it should work anywhere within that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're getting that error the only possible explanation is that the variable is not defined, which logically leads me to the conclusion that the file you edited is not the same controller that's calling your template.  This can happen if you are using any OCMOD which has an unchanged version of product.php in the cache, since OCMOD doesn't know about changes you've made until you do a refresh.  Do you have any OCMOD installed?  Have you tried refreshing the OCMOD cache since you made the change?

Comment: Yes, i have many MOD but none of those made any changes to `product.php` , no i didn't try to clear cach after these changes. i'll try. i'm a little sure i've edited right controller because other variable like `model` get data same as i did. i don't know.. but i if you read comment under the answer, Lucas did the same and works fine for him, but not working for me, both are same version of OC. I going to install new OC and test on it and found out what's the problem.

Comment: why don't you just clear the ocmod cache and let me know what happens. 9 times out of 10 this is the reason your changes aren't showing up.  another easy thing you can do is just add `die;` in the controller and see if it dies.  that's a sure fire way to know if your code is getting executed.

Comment: Thanks billynoah, problem solved, i cleared OCMOD cache and it works fine.. you made my day.